# Changing Cell Values in a Datatable Using Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I have a datatable with fields RoomNo, No. of Pax and Amount.

I also have a combo box with options "Room Rate" and "Package Rate". If Room Rate is selected, the datatable will be filled with data from the Room Rates Reference depending on what  room is displayed in datatable.

> Room Rate Reference:

```
RoomNo  MaxCapacity Amount
101     4   1, 200
102     4   1, 200
201     4   1, 500
202     5   1, 700
```

> atatable
>   D

```
RoomNo  No.OfPax    Amount
101     4           1, 200
202     3           500
```

If Package Rate is selected, textboxes will be displayed to input the sample below.

No. of Pax: 10
Rate Per Head: 950
Amount: 9, 500

In the datatable, column NoOfPax and Amount should be zero.

> Datatable

```
RoomNo  No. of Pax  Amount
101      0          0.00
202      0          0.00
```

Is it possible to do it without using   for loop (coz it may affect execution speed)?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Now research how to do it, make an attempt and, if you encounter an actual issue along the way, that would be the time to post a question here.  Questions of the form "I want to do this, tell me how" are not appropriate for SO.

Comment: I've been doing researches. What i have found is a direct update in database with conditions.

Comment: Perhaps you don't even want to use Linq. You can throw fancy lambda-expressions into `Parallel.ForEach();`, too. ;-)

Comment: @angel If you are using `DataTable` then you are giving up performance already. LINQ is slower than direct `for` loops and designed for querying data, not changing data. So use `for` loops and consider using POCO instead of `DataTable`.